# How to wrap something into a given class in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

I think the example is pretty self explaining. I want to give a class name or "example" as a parameter and then creating some instances of it with e1 and e2 as constructor arguments. The example could also look a bit different, the key point is: **How can I create an instance of a class that is given 'by name' or 'by example instance'.**

```
function h = wrap_and_do(name_or_empty_instance_of_wrapper_class, e1, e2)
   w1 = instantiate a comparator class with argument e1
   w2 = instantiate a comparator class with argument e2
   h = do_something(w1, w2);
end
```

In C++, one could use templates or a factory method. There are no templates in Matlab and I would like to avoid factory methods, since I would need to implement it for all possible wrapper classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend not to use strings, instead use a function handle to the constructor:

```
function h = wrap_and_do(constructor, e1, e2)
   w1 = constructor(e1)
   w2 = constructor(e2)
   h = do_something(w1, w2);
end
```

Called via:

```
wrap_and_do(@MyExampleClass,1,2)
```

If you have to use strings, use `str2func`